# Add array of strings to linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

My code is below. I am displaying the details, but not in a proper way. Can you please help me?

```
TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("DisplayName:"+strDisplayName);

TextView tv2=new TextView(this);
tv2.setText("Email:"+strEmail);

TextView tv3=new TextView(this);
tv3.setText("FirstName:"+strFirstName);

TextView tv4=new TextView(this);
tv4.setText("LastName:"+strLastName);

TextView tv5=new TextView(this);
tv5.setText("CreatedDate:"+strCreatedDate);

mProfileLayout.addView(tv1, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mProfileLayout.addView(tv2, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mProfileLayout.addView(tv3, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mProfileLayout.addView(tv4, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mProfileLayout.addView(tv5, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Please.. What is the 'proper' way that you talk about. You tell us there is a problem, but not what the problem is or how you want it to look. How in the world do you expect us to help you?

Comment: u can use listview inside linearlayout and call notifydatasetchanged() on list adapter when dataset changed

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all these TextViews in your xml? If you do then you can access them with

```
TextView tvX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewXid);
```

and then just set the text

```
tvX.setText(string);
```

And so you dont have to use `mProfileLayout.addView(....);`